# alive once alive forever?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-meaning, headlinese

**doubt**

Is it correct to say

> alive once alive forever

meaning *one who feels alive once lives forever*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obviously not a sentence. However, it is structured exactly the way that mottoes and such are generally structured in English. Some would prefer a comma in it:

> Alive once, alive forever

And that does reinforce the structure as two parallel adjective-adverb pairs.

So yes, it works as a motto or saying, and if you clarify the structure with a comma I think native speakers will reliably understand it the way you present it. Just don't mistake this for it actually being a valid sentence. Titles, headings, sayings and the like don't have to follow the normal rules.